# CSS column-count ignored when text length exceeds available space

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, line-breaks

I would like to add a newspaper look to an HTML page to print a PDF report based on it. One issue I ran into is that I have difficulties to automatically break a text to a "new page" (that is another `div` (?)) when I set a defined `height` to the text container `.newspaper`. My current code uses the CSS Multi-column Layout. Here, even though I set the property `column-count: 3` it adds a fourth column when it exceeds the available space.

What I would need is that the remaining text that cannot go into the third column continues in the first column again, but under the current text. Is this possible in a HTML setup?

```css
.newspaper {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 525px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 125px;
  break-after: auto;
}

.newspaper div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(66% - 10px);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -125px;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is such a nice headline!</h2>
<div class="newspaper">
  <div><span style="text-align: left">Fig. 1: A black box</span><svg width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" title="figure1"><rect width="450" height="50" fill="black"></rect></svg></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, your code works as expected. column-count is indeed to wrap content into columns alike a newspaper, but it is not meant to manage the whole document at once and wrap columns into rows . You need either to : **remove** `height: 525px;` from `.newspaper` (so the content will be dispatched into 3 columns with an height adapted to the amount of content) or dispatch you content into many .newspaper (3 columns) containers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Wrap a `.newspaper` div into `.main` div and add specific height into that.

```css
.main {
  height: 525px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.newspaper {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-fill: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 125px;
  break-after: auto;
}

.newspaper div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(66% - 10px);
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -125px;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is such a nice headline!</h2>
<div class="main">
  <div class="newspaper">
  <div><span style="text-align: left">Fig. 1: A black box</span><svg width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" title="figure1"><rect width="450" height="50" fill="black"></rect></svg></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may set a column-width to keep it easily readable and use mediaqueries to help it being responsive. It will span your content from 1 to X columns depending on the width avalaible of your media screen.

here an example to play with: *( or to fork https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZExPJWZ )*

**note** mediaqueries are used only because of your spanning element , column-width used on its own do not require mediaquerie to be responsive. To see behavior, run the snippet in fullpage mode, then resize your browser's window.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --colSize: 15em;
  --colGap: 40px;
  --colbound: calc(100vw - (var(--colGap) + var(--colSize) * 2));
}

.newspaper {
  column-width: var(--colSize);
  column-gap: var(--colGap);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  break-after: auto;
}

.newspaper div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: var(--colbound);
  left: calc(var(--colSize) + var(--colGap));
  min-width: var(--colSize);
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: justify;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: calc( 30em + 40px + 2em)) {
  .newspaper div {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .newspaper p:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>This is such a nice headline!</h2>
<div class="newspaper">
  <div><span style="text-align: left">Fig. 1: A black box</span><br><svg width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" title="figure1">
      <rect width="100%" height="50" fill="blue"></rect>
    </svg></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
    euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
```